Passive repeater for metal hangar at airport
I'm looking for a fix to an airport radio communication issue. I have an all-metal hangar and have no communication with tower from inside it.
One side of the hangar has line-of-sight with the tower and I'd like to assemble a passive repeater for the aviation voice frequencies (118-137MHz). Perhaps a small Yagi on the side of the hangar and a matched omnidirectional inside. I read elsewhere in this forum a suggestion to a similar question was given to put a Yagi antenna outside a building connected to a ground plane on the inside. I have no experience with antennas except buying the ARRL antenna book a few years ago and getting overwhelmed by too much information.  Any suggestions for best way to go about this?

I'm afraid the fact that this will involve specific regulations for aviation radio will put this out of scope for the amateur radio website.

You use the word "repeater" but I wonder if you really mean that. Are you just looking to hear the voice band in the hangar? Certainly, an externally mounted antenna will resolve that. However, if you really do mean "repeater," unless you are retransmitting over an amateur band (I'm not sure why you would) there are definitely serious regulatory issues to use the air bands (as @MarcusMüller is alluding to, I think) Perhaps update your question to clarify your real goal?

@DavidHoelzer: A "passive repeater" is just a pair of antennas connected by a cable.

It would be a very interesting experiment to see how effective a simple metal rod poking through the roof would be. Its length would be about 46 inches (1/2 wavelength @ 128 MHz), and you'd mount it with half inside and half outside (1/4 wavelength each side), by some means that keeps it insulated from the metal roof.
I'm picturing a piece of 1/4" × 20 threaded rod, with two nuts threaded on it to clamp a pair of plastic disks on either side of the roof opening.
